# random no generate(1-9) using 9 <div> without no repitation,,,,,

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to generate rnadom number(1-9) in 9 div's. How to avoid number repitations? But it's not working, why i cant get output? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Random_No</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rno.css">
<script src="rno.js" ></script>
</head>

<body class="outer" onload=random()>
<div id="input1" ></div>
<div id="input2" ></div>
<div id="input3" ></div>
<div id="input4" ></div>
<div id="input5" ></div>
<div id="input6" ></div>
<div id="input7" ></div>
<div id="input8" ></div>
<div id="input9" ></div>
<script>
function random()
{
var a=new Array("input1","input2","input3","input4","input5","input6","input7","input8","input9");
x=a.length;
var ran=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
   ran[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
}

for(var i=0 ; i<x ; i++)
{
   document.getElementById("a[i]").innerHTML=ran[i];
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to generate randoms from a set-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Random_No</title>

</head>
<body >
<div id= "input1"></div>
<div id= "input2"></div>
<div id= "input3"></div>
<div id= "input4"></div>
<div id= "input5"></div>
<div id= "input6"></div>
<div id= "input7"></div>
<div id= "input8"></div>
<div id= "input9"></div>
<script>
function random_no(){
    var  i=0, ran=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    while(i<9){     
        document.getElementById("input"+(++i)).innerHTML= 
        ran.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*ran.length),1);
    }
}
onload=random_no;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
document.getElementById("a[i]").innerHTML=ran[i];
```

By

```
document.getElementById(a[i]).innerHTML=ran[i];
```

And... why 2 loops ?

Comment: Just doing this won't prevent repeated numbers

Answer (score 1):

Because you only want a small set of items randomised with no repeats and to take each one, a Fisher-Yates shuffle would be very efficient here.

```
var inputs = [], i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i) // get each input
    inputs.push(document.getElementById('input' + i));

function shuffleArray(a) { // Fisher-Yates shuffle, no side effects
    var i = a.length, t, j;
    a = a.slice();
    while (--i) t = a[i], a[i] = a[j = ~~(Math.random() * (i+1))], a[j] = t;
    return a;
}

inputs = shuffleArray(inputs); // shuffle

for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) // give values (already shuffled)
    inputs[i] = i + 1;  // there will be no repeats because we're counting up
```

Comment: Whilst I said it can be _very efficient_, this answer is a concept and not optimsed (if you shuffle a literal array of numbers `1-9` then get the `<input>`s at the same time as setting them it may be more efficient), I wrote it this way so it should be easy to follow what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
document.getElementById("a[i]").innerHTML = ran[i];
```

to

```
document.getElementById(a[i]).innerHTML = ran[i];
```

because putting quotes around `a[i]` makes it look for an element whose id is actually "a[i]"

Comment: Note that this answer is only in response to why there is no output coming from your code. On mobile and its taking too long to type an answer. I'll edit later with an answer for no repeats. Though Paul S's answer is good for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the elements in another array, shuffle it and inject the random number in basically one chained operation using some array methods:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
[].map.call(divs, function(e, i) {
    return i;
}).sort(function() {
    return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
}).forEach(function(r, i) {
    divs[i].innerHTML = r;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EsGL3/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.sort()` with a random comparator to re-order the values:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FYRTJ/)

```
function random()
{
    var x = 9,
        ids = [ 'input1', 'input2', 'input3',
                'input4', 'input5', 'input6',
                'input7', 'input8', 'input9'
              ],
        values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        i = 0;
    Array.sort( values, function(a,b){ return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1; });
    for( ; i < x; ++i)
    {
        document.getElementById( ids[i] ).innerHTML = values[i];
    }
}
```